# What is the exact meaning of “blood-dimmed (tragedy),” and how does it pass current among Anglophones?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was drawn to the word, “blood-dimmed tragedy” in the following statement of Maureen Dowd’s article titled, “Peeping Barry” in June 8 New York Times:

> You could see the fear in his eyes, the fear that froze him in place,
>   after Andy Card whispered to W. in that Florida classroom that a
>   second plane had crashed into the twin towers. The **blood-dimmed
>   tragedy** of 9/11 was chilling. But instead of rising above the fear, W.
>   let it overwhelm his better instincts.

I know ‘blood-chilling’ and ‘blood-curdling’. But as I don’t know the word, “blood-dimmed,” I consulted English dictionaries at hand and online. None of OED, CED and Merriam-Webster includes this word and nor does Google Ngram register any incidence of “blood-dimmed.”

However, I found that “blood-dimmed tragedy” is a twist of “the blood-dimmed tide is loosed,” in William Butler Yeats’ “The Second Coming.”

> "Turning and turning in the widening gyre
>
> The falcon cannot hear the falconer;
>
> Things fall apart; the center cannot hold;
>
> Mere anarchy is loosed upon the world,
>
> **The blood-dimmed tide is loosed**, and everywhere
>
> The ceremony of innocence is drowned;"

I wonder why Dowd – I know she loves flowery expressions - doesn’t plainly say ‘the tragedy of 9/11 was blood-chilling / curdling’ instead of ‘the blood-dimmed tragedy of 9/11 was chilling.”

How does the word “blood-dimmed,” which I cannot find in any of mainstream English dictionaries, pass current among average English speaking people? Will I be frowned on, or not, if I say “I saw a  **blood-dimmed car accident** in my neighborhood yesterday” to my English speaking friend?

Comment: I don't know your friends: but I would certainly frown on anybody wishing to be understood speaking the way Maureen Dowd writes.

Comment: What @TimLymington said. But to be honest, I doubt if even Maureen Dowd could **speak** the way Maureen Dowd writes. She probably makes quite a lot of changes between the first draft and the final published versions of most of her pieces.

Comment: It's simply a typo.  The writer meant something like "blood-tinged".  The writer is well known for confused, mixed-up idioms, typo-like-errors that are muddled quotes, and so on, and it's just a typical unremarkable example of that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd probably raise some eyebrows if you used *blood-dimmed* in normal conversation. It's not at all a common usage, and I'd hazard a guess that even most native speakers wouldn't be too clear on the exact meaning (it's *dimmed = made dim, dark*, akin to [rivers dark with blood](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22rivers%20dark%20with%20blood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)).

I also doubt most people would recognise the allusion to Yeats’ poem, but it certainly seems to me most references to [blood-dimmed](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22wealth%20will%20out%20and%20on%20whom%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22blood%20dimmed%22&oq=%22blood%20dimmed%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.529410.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..16.psy-ab.MJSRAead11s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.d2k&fp=575db4e7c24bc40c&biw=1296&bih=930) in Google Books are followed by the word *tide*, and do in fact stem directly from “The Second Coming”.

In this case I think it's probably fair to say Dowd is aiming more for a sense of "scholarly erudition" than "flowery language". She probably knows most of her readers won't pick up on the reference, but she assumes the few that do will admire her for using it (and themselves for "getting it").

Comment: I can't support this. It's nothing more than the ubiquitous "mangled quote/idiom/phrase/whatever" that you constantly see in the NYT.

Comment: @Fattie: Are you implying that Dowd *herself* was unaware of the allusion? I'm not exactly one of her biggest fans, but I think that's vanishingly unlikely. And as StoneyB points out below, *Dowd has a pretty firm grip on how the language works.*

Comment: Howdy; to keep it simple, I'd just restate: "mangled idioms/phrases are ubiquitous in the NYT".

Comment: @Fattie: That's supremely unenlightening. Am I repeating myself if I say it seems pretty obvious that Dowd is a competent and well-read writer who deliberately alluded to Yeats’ poem? Does your repetition of *mangled idioms/phrases* imply you genuinely think she didn't know *exactly* what she was doing? Or do you just object to such "erudite, literary" techniques in general?

Comment: Yes, I actually doubt Ms. Dowd, specifically, necessarily *really "knew what she was doing"*.  Would you please note though that in my first comment above, I typed:  **I can't support this. It's nothing more than the ubiquitous "mangled quote/idiom/phrase/whatever" that you constantly see in the NYT.**  Pls note that I did not mention Dowd specifically, and, as it were, I really don't want to talk about her.

Comment: "Or do you just object to such "erudite, literary" techniques in general?"  I don't even follow that question or see how it's related?  You know how, in contemporary English generally ....... it's a commonplace problem that writers/speakers **mangle idiom**.  So, folks will use "snowclones" not even having a clue they are using one, will requote misquotes, will "tender hooks" sort of thing, will offer confusing "further extensions of existing tropes", and so on (the taxonomy of the *ways people fuck-up idiom these days!!* is an extensive discussion in itself).  The NYT is a prime example.

Comment: The Second Coming must be one of the best-known and most-quoted poems; I've heard a thousand centres that cannot hold and beasts slouching off to Bethlehem to be born. The poem refers to a number of 9/11-related ideas: the death of innocence, the failure of goodness, and the birth of new horrors; alluding to it seems appropriate in context (even if you're a big George W Bush fan).

Answer (score 9):

SUPPLEMENTARY:
I think FumbleFingers not only hits the nail on the head, he drives it pretty much home. This is just to countersink it by addressing this piece of your question:

> I wonder why Dowd [...] doesn’t plainly say ‘the tragedy of 9/11 was blood-chilling / curdling’ instead of ‘the blood-dimmed tragedy of 9/11 was chilling.”

Whatever her use of it, Dowd has a pretty firm grip on how the language works; so I think she says *blood-dimmed* rather than *blood-chilling* because that's what she means. *Dimmed* means made not just dim and dark but also *obscure*, difficult to make out; Dowd is suggesting that W's fear was aroused not just by the horror of the event but by its opacity.

Comment: I've been having a bit of a splurge today, and used up my ration of votes for the first time in ages. But when I get some more, I'll be sure and upvote you for *countersink* - best chuckle I've had all day! (The point you make is solid, too. Dowd's style might be a bit quirky, but she certainly knows her medium! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Glad you liked it. Particularly glad somebody out there knows about countersinking. Don't burn your vote for my sake - I CW'd it. I'd of just snuck it in as a brief comment but Yoichi-san makes me want to put out the extra effort.

Comment: @ StoneyB: I know what you mean. Yoichi's a really good questioner because he always does his homework before asking. Besides, you're quite right to call attention to the fact that Dowd was almost certainly aware of the "obscuring" implications. I must admit I tend to exude a certain "sniffiness" towards her turns of phrase, but that's because they would often be seriously out of place in normal conversation. In her actual context (well-lettered columnist), she's a careful and competent writer.

Comment: FumbleFingers. I didn’t know the word, ‘countersink.’ I didn’t get the idea of it from wikidictionary’s definition - a conical hole cut into a manufactured object, or the cutter used to cut such a hole to allow the head of a countersunk bolt or screw, when placed in the hole, to sit flush with or below the surface, - until I saw how it works in a demonstration in YouTube. Countersink, it’s a really good word that describes and sits well with the process I’m trying to get the idea of what writers mean through this site. I like this word. Thank you, as always.

Comment: @StoneyB:  Brainstorm (thanks to you).  Let's say a few friends are chatting, and Sam says something ill advised.  Sally reams him out in no uncertain terms, and then Ralph adds insult to injury by reaming Sam out a little more.   Sam says to Ralph:  "Sally already drove the nail home, Ralph.  You didn't have to countersink it."

Comment: @StoneyB:  From Eccelsiastes 12:11 (NIV):  "The words of the wise are like goads; their collected sayings like firmly embedded nails--given by one Shepherd."  No mention of countersunk, but Solomon's phrase comes pretty close to it.

Comment: @StoneyB. What does I 'CW'd' it mean? I'm delighted to glean it together with countersink into my vocabulary.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Local jargon - made it a Community Wiki as an additional signal that primary credit should go to FumbleFingers

Comment: @rhetorician, Yoichi: StoneyB's *countersinking* is pretty neat in context, but you have to be careful not to stretch the analogy too far. It's true the more forceful among us do like to *hammer home* a point in a debate, for example. But it's invariably *screws* which are *countersunk*. You wouldn't want anyone to be put in mind of things like *"When all you have is a hammer, everything (including a screw) looks like a nail"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Back in the dark ages when I worked in scene shops the act of sinking the head of a finishing nail into the surface of the wood with a nailset was called *countersinking*, and this use seems still to be common in the US: [Google "countersink nail"](https://www.google.com/search?q=countersink+nail&oq=countersink+nail&aqs=chrome.0.57j65l2j0l3.2368j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @ StoneyB: I stand corrected. I've always been told to ***punch*** them down (with a [nail punch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nail+punch+picture&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mUe2Ue2RH5SQ0QWVgYFI&ved=0CDIQsAQ&biw=1296&bih=930)), but obviously usages vary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard *set* a nail as well.

Comment: @FumbleFingers/StoneyB: Wikipedia provides an amusing addendum: Except in the most literal of cases where the opposite of using a golden hammer (in contrast to ‘When all you have is a hammer ...' ) would presumably be using the "right tool for the job," the antonym for this mindset would be "there's more than one way to skin a cat."

Comment: @YoichiOishi ! I am now trying to imagine skinning a cat with a hammer.

Comment: I suppose for that you'd need a [**claw** hammer!](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=picture+claw+hammer&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=yDW3UeaKFqOo0wWh64FQ&ved=0CD4QsAQ&biw=1296&bih=930) :)

Comment: "Tanning the hide" would take a wooden or rawhide hammer, or mallet.  Hammers are indispensable no matter the task (as an impact or force multiplier), so don't hesitate from using one.  Bigger is not always better though :)

Answer (score 0):

Per [enotes.com](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-drowns-the-ceremony-of-innocence-in-the-272404),

> The anarchy and blood-dimmed tide Yeats describes allude to the Russian revolution and World War I, both shocking and violent events in the European consciousness. A bloody tide seems to be rushing in everywhere. Because there is so much blood, innocence itself appears to have been drowned in it. People can no longer live in innocence, because too much death and violence has occurred.

So a blood-dimmed event would be shocking, violent, and bloody, affecting everything and everyone it touches.